# Flex: Child Canvas on top of Shapes

Tags: apache-flex

I have a master canvas and am adding child Canvases.  On my master canvas I have shapes added with baseCanvas.rawChildren.addChild(). But I want to draw canvases on top of the master canvas.  These canvases can be moved around with the mouse. Whenever I move a child canvas over a shape, the shape bleeds through.  It seems shapes rest on a layer above the child canvases.  Anyway to have shapes not bleed through other child canvases?

Comment: Have you tried creating another canvas for all your shapes and adding it first to your master canvas?

Comment: yeah, tried that.  found a solution though.  turns out I have to set the childIndex for rawChildren as opposed to simply the children.